# How to fix issues with SMB, Open Media Vault and IOS devices

Tags: nas, freenas, media-server

After following the instructions on building my NAS from here: [https://www.raspberrypi.com/tu…ox-raspberry-pi-tutorial/](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tu%E2%80%A6ox-raspberry-pi-tutorial/)

I found that whenever I tried to transfer files from my Iphone to my NAS I encountered one of the following issues:

- "Attribute not found"
- "OSStatus error 100093"

My system configuration is:

[image]

IOS 15.7

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

Services->SMB/CIFS->Shares->->Enable "Time Machine support"

That fixed all my issues.

[image]